# how to access the selected dropdown back to flask

Tags: javascript, python, html, jquery, flask

I have been trying to access the selected dropdown back to the `Flask` on a click of button. Based on one of the suggestions I did as follows

app.py

```
    @app.route('/ra/connect',methods=['GET','POST'])
    def connect_management():
       user = (request.form['selected_class']).first()
       return (str(user))
```

app.html

```
              <select name="selected_class" class="form-control" id="all_classes">

                  {% for o in all_classes %}
                  <option  value="{{ o }}" selected>{{ o }}</option>
                  {% endfor %}   
              </select>
```

I need to use the selected dropdown option and populate few more results from `Flask` api on a click of button and display them in `countdown` tag below the button. To sum up I need to access the dropdown value back to the `Flask` api without new tab.

```
<button class="form-control" id="button" onclick="connect4()">Get gateways</button>
                <p id="countdown"></p>
```

I have been getting

```
TypeError: 'ImmutableMultiDict' object is not callable
```

even after following the suggestions

Comment: Did you try to access the content with request.get_json() ? and then you can access your 'countdown' key in the JSON

Comment: yes it gave the same error

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot). There are other useful information.

Comment: if you want to add elements to page without reloading page then you need `JavaScript` (or `jQuery`) to send `AJAX` request, get result and update existing HTML in browser. I don't see JavaScript in your code.

Comment: I tried your code and I can't get this error. Probably you have it in different part of code - full error message should show you which line of code makes problem. But you didn't add full error message in question so we can't see it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't get your error with your code. Probably you get error for different code but you didn't show full error message which could confirm it.

---

To update `HTML` without reloading page you need `JavaScript` or `jQuery` to send `AJAX` request, get response and put it in existing `HTML`

Minimal working example:

```
from flask import Flask, request, render_template_string

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template_string('''<html>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-9/aliU8dGd2tb6OSsuzixeV4y/faTqgFtohetphbbj0=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<form action="/ra/connect" method="POST" id="form">
   <select name="selected_class" class="form-control" id="all_classes">
   {% for o in all_classes %}
      <option  value="{{ o }}" selected>{{ o }}</option>
   {% endfor %}   
   </select> 
   <button class="form-control" id="button">Get gateways</button>
</form>

<p id="countdown"></p>

<script>
    $('#button').click( function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        $.post("/ra/connect", $('#form').serialize(), function(data) {
            //alert(data);
            countdown = $("#countdown");
            countdown.append(data + "<br/>");
        });
    });
</script>
</html>''', all_classes=['Hello', 'World'])

@app.route('/ra/connect', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def connect_management():
    user = request.form.get('selected_class')
    print('user:', user)
    return str(user)

app.run()
```

---

**BTW:** Continuation in [flask variable access from HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62463469/flask-variable-access-from-html/)

Comment: it is returning None `127.0.0.1 - - [18/Jun/2020 13:22:03] "GET /cma/connect HTTP/1.1" 200 -
user: None`

Comment: do you means your code ? I don't use `/cma/connect` but `/ra/connect`. Maybe you have other differences which makes that your code doesn't work. You should put your code in question. BTW: maybe it displays `None` when you load page - I see `GET` in your comment but my code use `POST` when I click button.

Comment: i have compy pasted this code (with GET and POST) except i just replaced ra with cma

Comment: it has been the same `127.0.0.1 - - [19/Jun/2020 09:51:36] "POST /cma/connect HTTP/1.1" 200 -
user: None`

Comment: with my example you could get `None` if you change `name="selected_class"` to something different and then `request.form.get('selected_class')` will give `None` because form doesn't send value with this name. SO check if you use correct `name` in form and code. OR create new question and show your code which we could run and see your problem.

Comment: Ohh Okay that seems real problem; what should i do for it. should i use `all_classes` the `id` of the tag instead of `name`

Comment: form use only `name` to recognize elements. And in `all_classes` is list of strings displayed in selection - there is no `name` or `ID`. Maybe better create new question, show your current code because we only waste time on guessing.

Comment: or add your current code in question (but don't remove old code)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62463469/flask-variable-access-from-html i made a new question with all the details