# flask variable access from HTML

Tags: javascript, python, html, ajax, flask

app.py

```
@app.route('/cma/connect', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def connect_management():
    user = request.form.get('all_classes')
    print('user:', user)
    return str(user)
@app.route('/')
def index():
   return render_template('app.html',
                           all_classes=default_classes)
```

app.html

```
<select name="selected_cma" class="form-control" id="all_classes">

                      {% for o in all_classes %}
                      <option  value="{{ o }}" selected>{{ o }}</option>
                      {% endfor %}   
                  </select> 
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-xs-3">
                  <label for="all_entries">the manager</label>

                    <button class="form-control" id="button" onclick="connect()">the reciever</button>
                    <p id="countdown"></p>
```

js code inside the app.html

```
 $('#button').click( function(event) {
                event.preventDefault();

                $.post("/cma/connect", $('#form').serialize(), function(data) {
                    //alert(data);
                    countdown = $("#countdown");
                    countdown.append(data + "<br/>");
                });
            });
```

my result

```
user: None
127.0.0.1 - - [19/Jun/2020 10:03:11] "POST /cma/connect HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

what i want

```
user: (the selected option from the dropdown menu)
```

to conclude the problem

i want to get the selected option back to my flask api for further usage and display it without going to a new `tab`

are there any new ways?

Comment: you use wrong `name`. You have `<select name="selected_cma" ` so you should use `form.get('selected_cma')`

Comment: BTW: Code `$('#button').click(...)` assigns function to button and you don't need `onclick="connect()"`

Comment: with `selected_cma` it gave the same result `None` . the `connect()` has a differnt functionality

Comment: BTW: where do you have `<form action="/cma/connect" method="POST" id="form">` ? JavaScript use `'#form'` to get values from `<form ... id="form"` and you need it.

Comment: i tried doing that. but it takes results into a new tab. i want it just below the button

Comment: without `<form>` it is useless - and it would need more complex code in JavaScript. And if it opens in new tab then you have something else wrong. You have to create minimal working code with your problem.

Comment: with `form` tag also it gave `None` as result

Comment: did you add `<form>` with `id="form"`  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to use `<form>` in code (which is very strange) then you can try

```
<script>
    $('#button').click( function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        var selected = $("#all_classes :selected").val();

        alert("selected: " + selected);

        $.post("/ra/connect", {"selected_cma": selected}, function(data) {
            //alert(data);
            countdown = $("#countdown");
            countdown.append(data + "<br/>");
        });
    });
</script>
```

Rest should be the same.

`JavaScript` sends `{"selected_cma": selected}` so `Flask` has to use the same name in `form.get('selected_cma')`

```
@app.route('/cma/connect', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def connect_management():
    user = request.form.get('selected_cma')
    print('user:', user)
    return str(user)
```

and

```
<select name="selected_cma" class="form-control" id="all_classes">
    {% for o in all_classes %}
     <option  value="{{ o }}" selected>{{ o }}</option>
    {% endfor %}   
</select> 
</div>

<div class="form-group col-xs-3">
     <label for="all_entries">the manager</label>
     <button class="form-control" id="button">the reciever</button>
     <p id="countdown"></p>
```

And don't need `onclick="onclick()"` because `$('#button').click(...)` already assign function. And if you have some function `onclick()` then it can makes some other problems.

---

**EDIT:**

Minimal working code

```
from flask import Flask, request, render_template_string

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template_string('''<html>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-9/aliU8dGd2tb6OSsuzixeV4y/faTqgFtohetphbbj0=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

   <select name="selected_class" class="form-control" id="all_classes">
   {% for o in all_classes %}
      <option  value="{{ o }}" selected>{{ o }}</option>
   {% endfor %}   
   </select> 
   <button class="form-control" id="button">Get gateways</button>

<p id="countdown"></p>

<script>
    $('#button').click( function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        var selected = $("#all_classes :selected").val();

        alert("selected: " + selected);

        $.post("/ra/connect", {"selected_cma": selected}, function(data) {
            //alert(data);
            countdown = $("#countdown");
            countdown.append(data + "<br/>");
        });
    });
</script>
</html>''', all_classes=['Hello', 'World'])

@app.route('/ra/connect', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def connect_management():
    print(request.form)
    print(request.data)
    user = request.form.get('selected_cma')
    print('user:', user)
    return str(user)

app.run()
```

---

**BTW:** previous question: [how to access the selected dropdown back to flask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62428742/how-to-access-the-selected-dropdown-back-to-flask/)

Comment: THAT WORKS...!  this statement made it all ----> `{"selected_cma": selected}`